# Open a piped process (sqlplus) in perl and get information from the query?

Tags: sql, perl, unix, sqlplus

Basically, I'd like to `open` a pipe to sqlplus using Perl, sending a query and then getting back the information from the query.

Current code:

```
open(PIPE, '-|', "sqlplus user/password@server_details");

while (<PIPE>) {
    print $_;
}
```

This allows me to jump into sqlplus and run my query.

What I'm having trouble figuring out is how to let Perl send sqlplus the query (since it's always the same query), and once that's done, how can I get the information written back to a variable in my Perl script?

PS - I know about `DBI`... but I'd like to know how to do it using the above method, as inelegant as it is :)

---

Made some changes to the code, and I can now send my query to sqlplus but **it disconnects**... and I don't know how to get the results back from it.

```
my $squery = "select column from table where rownum <= 10;"

# Open pipe to sqlplus, connect to server...
open(PIPE, '|-', "sqlplus user/password@server_details") or die "I cannot fork: $!";
# Print the query to PIPE?
print PIPE $squery;
```

Would it be a case of grabbing the `STDOUT` from sqlplus and then storing it using the Perl (parent) script?

I'd like to store it in an array for parsing later, basically.

Flow diagram:

Perl script (parent) -> open pipe into sqlplus (child) -> print query on pipe -> sqlplus outputs results on screen (STDOUT?) -> read the STDOUT into an array in the Perl script (parent)

---

**Edit**: It could be that forking the process into sqlplus might not be viable using this method and I *will* have to use DBI. Just waiting to see if anyone else answers...

Answer (score 5):

Forget screen scraping, Perl has a perfectly cromulent [database interface](http://dbi.perl.org).

Comment: Just modified my question. Thanks for pointing it out anyway!

Answer (score 3):

I think you probably want [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.89/lib/IPC/Run.pm).  You'll be using the `start` function to get things going:

```
 my $h = start \@cat, \$in, \$out;
```

You would assign your query to the `$input` variable and pump until you got the expected output in the `$output` variable.

```
$in = "first input\n";

## Now do I/O.  start() does no I/O.
pump $h while length $in;  ## Wait for all input to go

## Now do some more I/O.
$in = "second input\n";
pump $h until $out =~ /second input/;

## Clean up
finish $h or die "cat returned $?";
```

This example is stolen from the CPAN page, which you should visit if you want more examples.

Comment: And can I do it without installing this module/library?

Comment: @Az, yes you can (see the core module IPC::Open2), but God help the person who tries it for the first time, after about the fourth rewrite because you found some weird obscure behavior that you never would have thought could happen you will wish you just used a well tested module.

Answer (score 0):

If your query is static consider moving it into it's own file and having `sqlplus` load and execute it.

```
open(my $pipe, '-|', 'sqlplus', 'user/password@server_details', '@/path/to/sql-lib/your-query.sql', 'query_param_1', 'query_param_2') or die $!;

while (<$pipe>) {
    print $_;
}
```

Comment: Just checking: all the 'arguments' after `-|` are the ones being fed to the bash process, right? To `open` that's just one massive argument, yarp?

Comment: @Az, not exactly, providing `open` a list instead of a single command name `bash` is never called. This limits quite a few code injection vectors, but also prevents you from using features of `bash` in the command itself. Can you provide more detail than 'didn't work'? Is there an error output? `sqlplus` expects that you will use it interactively after the file is executed so you might need to end the sql file with `exit` for the `while` loop to terminate. You can also test the command from the command line separate from the Perl script to see if it is a Perl side or a sqlplus side issue.

Comment: The password has some characters that need to be broken out using `\` so the single-quotes don't play nicely with it.

Comment: Sorry about that (I got logged out and random stuff happened). Anyhoo, I appreciate the suggestion but I'd really like to continue from where I'm stuck (update to the question). :) (PS - This is where I mention that I'm quite new to Perl).

Answer (score 0):

if you're doing this in unix, it's easy.  I haven't figured out a good way to do it in windows yet.  The $result variable below will have the output of the query.  I use a field separator so it's easy to parse afterwards:

$result = `$oracle_home/bin/sqlplus -S "/nolog"<<EOF1 connect system/PASSWORD\@INSTNACE set heading off; set linesize 300; set feedback off; set pagesize 0; select username || '+---+' || created || '+---+' || profile || '+---+'  from dba_users order by username; exit EOF1` ;

print $result . "\n";